# Washer tripping gfi outlet

Tags: electrical, basement, washing-machine, gfci

I've been living in my house for almost two years and my washer and dryer have been working fine. I have a maytag Neptune washer and dryer, just the other day I took a packet of tide washing machine cleaning powder for front loaders and ran it through. This is the first time I have attempted to do this and yesterday I went to put in a load of laundry only to fine out that the washer is still full of water and didn't finish the cycle! So I tried to restart it and nothing worked on the washer then I realized it tripped the gfi outlet so I reset it and tried to start it again. It starts and begins spinning and then it trips the outlet again! I'm at loss what to do!

Comment: This isn't the first time Tide has wreaked havoc on an electrical system.

Comment: So if I would replace the outlet do you think it would fix it? I can do anything with the washer because it keeps tripping it and the washer still has water in it

Comment: Try to plug something else into the washer outlet, like a microwave or toaster and turn on. If the gfci trips, then you need to replace it.  If it doesn't, you may have an electrical problem with your washer or line wiring.